# joining and inserting into same table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query which runs in SQL Server 2000.

```
INSERT INTO #Student
   select a,b,c
   from ID i
   inner join #student t on i.ID = t.ID
```

But in SQL Server 2008 it doesn't run.. any idea how to get around this?

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: Did you create the table #student first?

Answer (score 1):

You really need to give us more information than you've provided if you want a solution.  Maybe include some sample data for the tables in the SQL statement and/or some sample output that is expected.

Here's one example how you could make the above SQL statement work.  I could easily come up with a dozen more examples to make it work, but we'll never know if it will work for you without additional information about your problem.

```
CREATE TABLE ID (ID int, a char(1), b char(2), c char(3))
INSERT ID SELECT 1, 'a', 'b', 'c'
INSERT ID SELECT 2, 'a', 'b', 'c'

CREATE TABLE #Student (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), a1 char(1), b1 char(2), c1 char(3))
INSERT #Student SELECT 'a', 'b', 'c'
INSERT #Student SELECT 'a', 'b', 'c'

INSERT INTO #Student
SELECT a, b, c
  FROM ID i
  JOIN #student t 
    ON i.ID = t.ID

SELECT *
  FROM #Student
```